# Minimum Space for Boot Camp Windows 8.1

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition, disk-space

I have a Macbook Pro 2014 13-inch 128 GB and I want to install Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2013 Community via Boot Camp. I am Mac user and use my Mac for iOS development. Now I have to learn Windows app development, so I need Windows 8.1 + Visual Studio 2013 Community. I have no plan to spend my money for new Windows PC/Laptop. I am not familiar using Boot Camp features so it's my first leap.

1. How much space to install Windows 8.1 + Visual Studio 2013 Community via Bootcamp? FYI I have 100 GB free on my OSX Yosemite and I have no plans to save any documents or media files on Windows.
2. If I divide 40 GB for OS X and 60 GB for Windows and then I don't need my Windows anymore, can I move my 60 GB back to the OS X partition?

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed your info.plist in boot camp assistant so you can use a .iso file for windows 8.1?

If you havn't follow my steps!

Find Boot Camp Assistant then DUPLICATE IT put it on your desktop right click it show package contents open info.plist then find PreUSBSupportedModels and remove the Pre JUST THAT save and open! then download a ISO

( Look up a activation key )

Here is download 
( Dont need key to download )

https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows8

Always STAY cool!

By the way this is just so you dont lose storage on your HD Harddrive

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.1 requires 20 GB.<sup>[[1]](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-8/system-requirements)</sup> Visual Studio requires 8 GB.<sup>[[2]](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs.aspx)</sup>

At least 10-15% free space is recommended, thus 32 GB is the bare minimal, not counting Boot Camp drivers and other software you'll probably want like a browser (and its cache). And paging. And a hibernation file. And AppData. Now you're up to about 50 GB.

You can always repartition the disk, but it's not always straightforward and you don't want to be doing it regularly.

Comment: So i can repartition my Disk? To do that, should i delete my Windows first? By the way, thanks for the answer

Comment: @Aji If you use Boot Camp Assistant to delete Windows, it will add the space back to your OS X partition. If you just want to adjust the sizes, you can do it with something such as iPartition.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to running Windows on a Mac is to do it in a virtual machine using VMware Fusion, Parallels Desktop for Mac and or VirtualBox.

This is the route I'd recommend when dealing with such small internal physical storage as one can have better control over the space Windows and necessary Win Apps take up. Initially only the space necessary is taken up and the virtual hard disk grows as needed up to the size limit set.  The virtual disk can be resized, if necessary, more easily then a physical disk can too.

The VM's can also be run from an external drive as well.  Something to consider if you really do not need to run Windows natively on physical hardware.

During my Windows Development days I ran Visual Studio exclusively in virtual machines, thus never trashing the Host with errant code written in the middle of then night when I was to tired to see what I was doing. :)

Comment: Great thanks. Honestly i need to run Windows on native way, not using virtual machine such as VMware, parallels, etc. Not only for focusing the task i do, but also i can use more and better resource of my Macbook rather than using Virtual machine. I'm just wondering that Virtual Machine will take down my Macbook performance. So, the safe way is Bootcamp rather than Virtual Machine. 

Thanks for the answer...

Comment: @user343, Re "I ran Visual Studio exclusively in virtual machines", it slow?

Comment: @Pacerier, I did not find it to be slow, but that is subjective. It worked just fine for _my_ needs. YMMV